# Linking cluster to a Class

Tags: database, oop, graph, orientdb

Suppose I have A as an abstract class and B extends A class C extends A as well now I add D cluster to B 
and G cluster to C and now I want to link G cluster to B as well how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create vertices on specific clusters, example:

```
Vertex v1 = g.addVertex( "class:B,cluster:D" );
Vertex v2 = g.addVertex( "class:C,cluster:G" );
Edge e = v1.addEdge( "links", v2 );
```

Look at the [official documentation](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html#create-vertices-and-edges-in-specific-clusters).